# Django: How to make it such that I can submit interest to any blogpost, not just 1 blog post?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Django: How to make it such that I can submit interest to any blogpost, not just 1 blog post?
Currently, now after I submit interest to a blogpost, I can no longer submit interest to any other blog post.  I will receive this message saying that 'You have already submitted your interest to this post.' Even though i haven't.

Judging by the nature of my model. Is there a way for me to filter the 'user' field in my interest model such that I am only checking through to see if the particular user in that particular blog post has already submitted the interest?

Cause i understand that right now, they are filtering it based on all the blogpost, and as long as I have already submitted 1, it definitely exists. Please let me know if you need my forms.py , urls.py too if it helps.

views.py

```
def submit_interest_view(request, slug):
    form = SubmitInterestForm()
    user = request.user
    blog_post = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    num_blogpost = BlogPost.objects.filter(author=user).count()
    if blog_post.author.email == user.email:
        return HttpResponse('You cannot submit interest to your own post.')
    if Interest.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists() and request.method=="POST": 
        return HttpResponse('You have already submitted your interest to this post.')
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        form = SubmitInterestForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.user = user
            obj.blog_post = blog_post
            obj.save()
            InterestInvite.objects.create(interest=obj)
            messages.success(request, 'Your interests have been submitted', extra_tags='submittedinterest')
            return redirect(reverse('HomeFeed:main')) 
         else:
            messages.warning(request, 'Something went wrong. Please try again..', extra_tags='wronginterest')
            return render(request, "HomeFeed/submitinterest.html", {'form': form,'user': user, 'num_blogpost': num_blogpost, 'blog_post': blog_post}) 
    else:
        form = SubmitInterestForm()  
    return render(request, "HomeFeed/submitinterest.html", {'form': form,'user': user, 'num_blogpost': num_blogpost, 'blog_post': blog_post})
```

models.py

```
class Interest(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   timestamp        = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   is_active            = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=False, default=True)
   my_thoughts         = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False)
   blog_post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class BlogPost(models.Model):
 chief_title            = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
 body                   = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False)
 author                     = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 slug                   = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do check if there is already existing Interest object

```
Interest.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists():
```

instead of looking if there is Interest row for that users on particular post

```
Interest.objects.filter(user=request.user, blog_post=blog_post).exists()
```

Comment: Hi i tried your method but got this error instead: `IntegrityError at /HomeFeed/submitinterest/testuser1-12
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "HomeFeed_interest_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) already exists.`

Comment: You have OneToOneField instead of ForeignKey

Comment: So I need to change it to foreign key is it? Will it affect the rest of my other codes? @iklinac

Answer (score 0):

Your problem because of this condition.

```py
if Interest.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists() and request.method=="POST": 
        return HttpResponse('You have already submitted your interest to this post.')
```

It should be changed to like below:

```py
if Interest.objects.filter(user=request.user, blog=blog_post).exists() and request.method=="POST": 
        return HttpResponse('You have already submitted your interest to this post.')
```

**Explain:** Code above means you need to find *a `Interest` is created when a specific `User` interesting in a specific `BlogPost`*  but you *find a `Interested` created when `User` interesting in **any** `BlogPost`*

Comment: Hi i think you meant `blog_post=blog_post` right?

Comment: Anyway I tried but now i receive this error instead: `IntegrityError at /HomeFeed/submitinterest/testuser1-12
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "HomeFeed_interest_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) already exists.`

Comment: My mistake, blog_post=blog_post.

Comment: Your IntegrityError because you are using ForeignKey. It should be ManyToMany (A `BlogPost` can be interesting by many `User`)